# Object Tracking OpenCV GPU / CUDA

Tags: opencv, gpu

I'm trying to track objects very fast using my gpu. 
I've already done this one the CPU by

1. background Subtraction
2. contour Finding
3. Meanshift

But I cannot find anything in the OpenCV CUDA-Modul equal to the contour Finding algorithm. Background Subtraction works already very fast. Is there another way for object tracking using the GPU in OpenCV, CUDA Module?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are right, there is no contour-finding algorithm in the CUDA module of OpenCV -because this algorithm is hard to optimize for the GPU.

But you could use [optical flow](http://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d7/d3f/group__cudaoptflow.html#gsc.tab=0). 
For doing this, you would have to find some features in the background-subtracted image; for example edges/corners or you could use GoodFeaturesToTrack, too.